# Trouble with WCF configuration in asp .net

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services, web-applications, wcf-binding

I have a 5 layer application (Entity, Data Access, Business, UI and Exception) in my Visual Web developer express 2010. My Data Access Layer being a WCF Service and UI being asp .net web application. I added service reference to the Business Layer and dragged the app config file to the UI Layer. When I run the app, I get the following error

> Could not find default endpoint element that references contract
>   'ExcelService.IExcelReader' in the ServiceModel client configuration
>   section. This might be because no configuration file was found for
>   your application, or because no endpoint element matching this
>   contract could be found in the client element.

Answer (score 3):

The content of the `app.config` will need to be merged with the `web.config` file that's already present.

Specifically, you'll find a `<system.serviceModel>` section in the `app.config` file. Take this whole section and copy it into `web.config` - your UI layer should then see the WCF configuration.

Your `web.config` will then look a little like this:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
     <!-- application settings -->
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
     <!-- configuration for Web application -->
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
     <!-- configuration for WCF -->
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: when i added it under the <configuration> web config i got... "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:49171"

Comment: @user841923 - then you have a different problem! Do you have the WCF service running on your local machine?